# Divide component which has cascading comboboxes at angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have an angular 6 app. And, I created shared `country-state` component. It is working perfectly.

[PERFECTLY WORKING EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3pqgk?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcountry-state%2Fcountry-state.component.ts)

But, when I divide my `country-state` to `country` and `state` component, I can't fill states of selected countries. How can I change my `not working example`?

[NOT WORKING EXAMPLE](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-yw4s6u?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcountry%2Fcountry.component.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the service add a public variable for set the  country id and create a method to filter by country id

```
  countryId = null;

  filterStates(){
    if(!this.countryId) return null;
    return this.getStates().filter((item) => item.countryid == this.countryId);
  }
```

Then from the country component set the country id

```
onSelect(countryid) {
 this.selectService.countryId = countryid;
}
```

from the state component, call the filtering method

```
 get states(): State[]{
     return this.selectService.filterStates();
  };
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdqtha?file=src%2Fapp%2Fstate%2Fstate.component.ts)

Comment: My problem is when I select country, I want to fill only states of selected country. But, in your example listing all states @SachilaRanawaka . You can see from my stackblitz link of perfectly working example.

Comment: yeah, now I understood the issue. check this new demo. https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xdqtha?file=src/app/state/state.component.ts